# Changing name/location of jboss-log4j.xml on server startup

Tags: configuration, jboss, log4j

In my case I have a jboss-5.1 which should pull different `jboss-log4j.xml`, based on their startup call. Unluckily I was unable to find something like the `-Dlogging.properties=` for xml-files, to supply different xml-files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood your question, you want JBoss not to use the default conf/jboss-log4j.xml file, but use instead another one defined as a property in the start up script. In that case you should:

1) Modify the ConfigurationURL attribute of the Log4jService defined in the file *conf/jboss-service.xml*. The original looks like:

```
  <attribute name="ConfigurationURL">resource:jboss-log4j.xml</attribute>
```

Instead you should tell JBoss to take the file from a property (let's name this property *log4j.conf.file*, for example), so it would be:

```
  <attribute name="ConfigurationURL">${log4j.conf.file}</attribute>
```

2) And then, start up the JBoss instance defining this property, and setting its value to the exact route of the log4j xml configuration file you want to use for this instance. For example, if the route to this file is "*/app/jboss/logconf/log4j.xml*":

```
  ./run.sh -Dlog4j.conf.file=/app/jboss/logconf/log4j.xml
```

Comment: @toni-s-magraner Thanks for your input. Unluckily the setting is not respected on my windows 7-box. I changed the opts to apply `-Dlog4j.configuration.XmlFile=C:/log4j.xml` (which shows up in the java-opts correctly, but unluckily it is still pulling the original jboss-log4j.xml

Comment: I tested it in Linux Ubuntu with Jboss EAP 5.1.2, and it worked.  It's strange, the OS used shouldn't affect. I'll try to test it in a Windows environment and I'll let you know my results. :-)

Comment: I changed your example a bit, since both files reside inside the standard config directory. If I change to jboss-service.xml to point directly to `resource:jboss-log4j-local.xml` it works perfectly, if I write this into a `-Dlog4j.configuration.XmlFile=resource:jboss-log4j-local.xml` it falls back to standard `jboss-log4j.xml`. Removing `resource:` doesn't change anything.

Comment: mmm, it should still work with the changes you applied, you can name the property as you want (unless you use a property name that already exist). So, did you try with the jboss-service.xml line like: <attribute name="ConfigurationURL">${log4j.configuration.XmlFile}</attribute>,  and the start up OPTS as you stated in the first comment?

Comment: You are totally right, it works. My script overwrote the property in a later state.